# How can I tell whether a character is male or female?

Tags: crusader-kings-3

I know, just look at the portrait, right?  But I have this two-year-old kid in my prison that my soldiers captured after a siege, and I'm honestly not sure if they're a girl or a boy:

[image: Screenshot]

- The portrait looks pretty ambiguous, and it doesn't help that I'm playing in a new part of the map (west Africa) so I'm not familiar with all the character models yet.
- The name also doesn't say anything to me.
- The line under the name that often says "Son of *X*" or "Daughter of *X*" just says "Your Prisoner".
- I can't look at their sexuality icon, since, well, the kid is two years old and doesn't have one yet.
- For the same reason (and because my character is also a child) there are no right-click menu options to marry, seduce or romance them.
- I don't even seem to be able to arrange a betrothal for them, either directly or via their liege.  I guess you can't betroth a prisoner?
- None of the tooltips or dialog boxes that I've tried refers to them as "he" or "she".  And I've tried quite a few.  They all just use the kid's name, or don't refer to him/her directly at all.
- I don't think there's any way to figure out their gender based on inheritance, either, since all titles they have a claim to have equal inheritance law.

So, any other suggestions?  I suppose I can just wait until they get older, but surely there's some better way.

(Ps. I did eventually find a solution, kind of, and I've posted it below.  But I'm still hoping that there's some easier and better way that I've missed.)

Answer (score 5):

While writing this question, I did eventually find *one* available interaction with a dialog box that actually uses a pronoun:

[image: Screenshot of "Move to Dungeon" dialog in Crusader Kings 3 showing female pronoun]

Of course, this isn't exactly a general solution, since it only works on your prisoners.  But hopefully most non-prisoner characters will have *some* other interaction available that refers to them with a pronoun or otherwise reveals their gender.

---

Also, I did come up with a general solution of sorts: search for the character's name using the general character finder (from the menu at the bottom of the screen) and, once you find them, use the "Gender" filter to see if they're male or female:

[image: Screenshot]

But while this method should always work, it's pretty awkward, since opening the character finder and setting the appropriate filters takes quite a few clicks.  I'm really hoping there's some quicker way.

Answer (score 4):

This is a only slightly better solution, but it does save a few clicks. If you check the traits and personality descriptions they will generally reference gender.

For example, this 4 year old gambler: [image]

The traits also seem to have gender descriptors which at least saves a few clicks:
[image]

An example of a young, jailed, and balanced individual
[image]
[image]

Comment: That's a good suggestion. The particular character this question arose with didn't have any traits, though, and her personality was listed as just "balanced". I can't remember if I tried looking at the tooltip for it and found no pronouns, or if I just missed it.

Comment: I checked balance characters as well, they also show a gender.

Comment: To add to the confusion, I've seen characters misgendered in a few different dialogues. Usually, I go to the character's parents and hover over their portrait in the children section. It should say son or daughter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure when exactly this got added, but Paradox made this much easier in one of the patches since this question was first asked!

Simply hover over the sexuality of the character, and it will helpfully list both sexual orientation and sex!

[image]